# Vim Editor->clang_complete: no python support available

Tags: python, vim, clang, code-completion, clang-complete

Case: Testing clang_complete with gVim 7.3

I installed MinGW, then followed the tutorial [here](http://bencode.net/clangonwindows) to download and compile clang. It compiled for around an hour, then **make install**. Clang worked. I especially love the error annotation. It's amazing.

Now comes the case of clang_complete. I Installed it. I am using pathogen, so clang_complete fron github comes in bundle folder inside vimfiles.

I opened the vim editor and gave command **:scriptnames**. It shows clang_complete plugin. **:version** shows it has python entry, so vim was built with python support. 
Also my test system has python installed.

but whenever I issue **:save foo1.cpp** , vim give this error,

Error detected while processing  function 14_ClangCompleteInit..14_initClangCompletePython:
line2 
clang_complete:No python support available
line 3
cannot use clang library.

simply puzzled.

*I have python installed on my system.
I Also tried using libclang library path for clang_complete as mentioned in another question on clang_complete here, but to no avail.*

Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure but python is in your path right?

Comment: Could you add the lines in `:version` that show that you have python support? Also what version of Python do you have?

Comment: Looks like your Vim compiled without python support.

Comment: Python is in path. Issuing :version command includes +python/dyn and +pyhton3/dyn in the feature list. I am using gvim73 from [here](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/vim/gvim73.zip) and system has python-2.7.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim needs to be compiled with Python support, i.e. `+python` when doing `:version`. `-python` means it's not installed. Taken from [clang_complete at Github](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete):

> You need Vim 7.3 or higher, compiled with python support and ideally,
>   with the conceal feature.

You said you had this enabled, but it doesn't look like it. Taken from `clang_complete.vim`.
This is the only place that error message is defined and triggers on `!has('python')`. In other words this doesn't seem to be a clang_complete issue, but rather that your install is missing or is having problems with Python support.

```
function! s:initClangCompletePython()
  if !has('python')
    echoe 'clang_complete: No python support available.'
    echoe 'Cannot use clang library'
    echoe 'Compile vim with python support to use libclang'
    return 0
  endif
  [..]
```

Comment: With Reference to Your first comment.. the vim editor has python as an included feature. (+python/dyn and +pyhton3/dyn ). I Studied the above function in conjunction with :version output..this is EXACTLY what puzzles me.

Comment: @EvdoCdma Have you tried any other plugins that require `+python` to locate if it's an error with clang_complete or your install of Vim's Python support?

Comment: I have tried ultisnips, and it is causing gvim to close down immediately. There are issues from python support on windows 8. Quite sure now. Thank you.

Comment: @EvdoCdma Aye, I thought as much. It'd be -really- weird if something would make the basic `has()` function buggy. Hopefully you'll be able to solve whatever problem is related to Windows 8. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this issue, invoking `:version` returns for features:

```
-python
+python3
```

So it seems this is caused by incompatible plugin that requires python (e.g. 2.x) but only python 3.x is available.